# Reviewing past reputation raises error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

When I go to my profile, click on the "reputation" tab, and choose either the "post" or "time" views, I get the error message "Error occurred when loading post body" when trying to open a past date (one that is not yet open). At least one other user has verified that they also have this problem.

Martin Sleziak supplied [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjyfB.png).

Comment: I just checked, happens to me as well.

Comment: Same thing here. Don't they do any kind of thorough testing of the code before an 'upgrade' is released?

Comment: I've posted about it at [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113366/error-message-when-trying-to-review-old-reputation-days); I know it's not required any more, but I hoped (and was successful at) someone would add more technical info to the issue. No replies yet.

Comment: @Arturo: thanks for passing the bug up the chain. I am not getting the error message any more, but trying to open a past date gives no response.

Comment: @robjohn: I'm still getting the error message.

Comment: @Arturo: I am getting the error message again, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was fixed in a build last night.  We made a last minute change to put the calls Google shouldn't be crawling under `/ajax/` (for lack of a better term), but the URL the reputation expansion hits to load got missed.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this.